# Angular Universal + lazyLoading module + http request

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, universal

I try to render data from http response in lazy loading module. SSR not render it source code.

When it is not in lazyLoading SSR render it.

Is there any way to render data in AngularUniversal when using lazyLoading routing module?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dane',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dane/dane.module').then(m => m.DaneModule)  // http reponse not render
      }
    ],

    children: [
       {
         path: 'dane',
         component: DaneComponent   // http response is render
       }      
    ]
  },
]
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dane',
  templateUrl: './dane.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dane.component.scss']
})
export class DaneComponent implements OnInit {

  el: any = {
    hero_image: ''
  };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts').subscribe(data => {
      this.el = data;
    })
  }

}
```

```
hero: <b>{{ el.hero_image }}</b>
```

Comment: What backend stack are you using? Are you using `PreloadAllModules`? Are you hosting the website on Plesk, or is the problem locally too?

Comment: ExpressJS like default Angular Universal use. I try preloading all modules but it is not working or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: So the API running on `localhost:3000` is an Express server? Not ASP.NET Core or Symphony?

Comment: And I was asking about Plesk because: Plesk does not allow webrequests sent back to the api by Node during SSR.

Comment: http://localhost:3000 is expressJS server or json-server. I tried both.